# 2008 R2 RDS Session Host and USB not working after disconnection/reconnect session

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services

We recently deployed a Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Session Host for our 2008R2 farm.

The users frequently disconnect from a session at one computer (nurse station) and reconnect to the session from another computer (patient room station).  They can do this back and forth multiple times a day.

It seems an initial login, to a station with a USB barcode scanner, will allow them to utilize the scanner in their Remote Desktop session. If they are reconnecting to a session, to a station with a USB barcode scanner, they cannot utilize the scanner in their Remote Desktop session.

I would presume this is because the session only scans for USB device events to map on initial logon AND/OR when you physically add a new device (ie. USB drive).

I'm looking for a solution to do the scan for USB devices to access at a set interval or upon reconnection to an existing session.

Please and thank you.

Comment: Those barcode scanners are a bitch, and (IME) it's probably the application or driver that accepts the scans from the USB device that's not playing well with a reconnected session.  Best way to see would be to restart the app or disconnect/reconnect the device from one of these reconnected sessions, it should be easy to hack up a reasonable workaround based on restarting the app or forcing a reconnect of the device from a shortcut or with [an event-based trigger for a scheduled task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for that info. I didn't realize that the .rdp was missing the redirect all supported PnP devices.

devicestoredirect:s:*

I will remain hopeful that this fixes issue but chances are it won't. I'll update you as soon as I test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize that the .rdp was missing the redirect all supported PnP devices.

You can add the following to the .rdp file

`devicestoredirect:s:*`

or Click the very bottom 2 options,

*"Supported Plug and Play Devices > Devices that I plug in later"*

[image: RDP Connection Options]